# Invoke parent constructor with named parameter

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to embed a POGO in a Java application. I want to use the POGO to instantiate the POJO with some dummy data for testing. I thought it would be possible for the POGO to extend the POJO and invokes the POJO's constructor with named parameters like in this example:

The Java class:

```
public class Pojo {
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

The Groovy class:

```
class Pogo extends Pojo {
  Pogo() {
    super(name: 'test name')
  }
}
```

Trying to instantiate the Pogo from a JUnit test via

```
@Test
public void shouldInitPojoWithTestData() {
    Pojo p = new Pogo();

    assertNotNull(p);
    assertEquals("test name", p.getName());
}
```

fails with

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: Pojo(java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

However, instantiating the POJO with named parameters in a Groovy script works fine:

```
def p = new Pojo(name: 'test name')
assert p.name == 'test name' // OK
```

Why can't I invoke a parent constructor with named parameters?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named constructor arguments is a kind of syntactic sugar. It will be translated to a chain, started with default parameterless constructor, and then followed by mutator calls.

For example, when you called

```
def p = new Pojo(name: 'test name')
```

It will be translated to:

```
def p = new Pojo()
p.setName('test_name')
```

`super` call is a direct call to parent class constructor. Named parameters consolidated to a Map instance, then, we try to call `super` with a single map argument.

And compiler tells you, that there is no such constructor.

You can declare it and manually extract fields value from given map, but in Java it would be unrobust(manually, like this.name = map.get("name")) or complicated(via reflexion).

You can use factory method in your POGO, to create pojo. Like this

```
class POGO {
   static Pojo createPOJO() {
       new Pojo(name: 'test_name')
   }
}
```